# How do you change the style attribute on a TreeGrid PropertyColumn?

Tags: java, wicket, treegrid

I want to set the style attribute of a `com.inmethod.grid.column.PropertyColumn` within a `com.inmethod.grid.TreeGrid`. The creation of the column is done as follows:

```
private PropertyColumn<DefaultTreeModel, DefaultMutableTreeNode, ConfigParamTreeNode> createCurrentValueColumn() {
    PropertyColumn<DefaultTreeModel, DefaultMutableTreeNode, ConfigParamTreeNode> col = new PropertyColumn<DefaultTreeModel, DefaultMutableTreeNode, ConfigParamTreeNode>(
            new Model<String>("Value"), "userObject.currentValue") {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 3525654933636874042L;

        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        @Override
        public boolean cellClicked(IModel rowModel) {
            ConfigParamTreeNodeModel treeNodeModel = (ConfigParamTreeNodeModel) (((DefaultMutableTreeNode) rowModel
                    .getObject()).getUserObject());
            treeNodeModel.getNodeLabel();
            AjaxRequestTarget target = AjaxRequestTarget.get();

                confirm.open(target);
            }
            return true;
        }

    };

    col.setResizable(true);
    return col;
}
```

Which displays a popup dialog when the user clicks the cell.
After the dialog is dismissed, I want to do some validation on the value, and indicate any error on the cell. So my idea was to set a red border around it. But my problem is, how do I get the `<div>` element associated with the cell, to set the style attribute on??

This can be done on a `PropertyTreeColumn` because it provides a `newNodeComponent`, in which you can access the Component object to set the style.

But how to do this on a `PropertyColumn`?

Or if someone can recommend a way of doing validation on a TreeGrid, and how to indicate errors on an individual cell basis I would be very interested in your ideas.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to override the PropertyColumn method getCellCssClass(), something like that:

```
PropertyColumn column = new PropertyColumn( columnId,new Model<String>( columnName ),
                                          somePropertyExpression,
                                          sortProperty ) {

       @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
       @Override
       public String getCellCssClass( IModel rowModel,
                                      int rowNum ) {

          if( getId().equals( "testid" ) ) {
                return "testCell";
          } else if( getId().equals( "blablaId" ) ) {
                return "blablaCell";
          } else {
                return null;
          }
      }
};
```

Comment: I think this will work, thanks. I notice that the rowNum parameter always gets passed in with a value of -1. But I can match up the rowModel with the one that got passed in to cellClicked().